# Addition and multiplication recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to write a recursive function that adds the following number to an odd number, and multiplies by the following number if the number is even. Essentially:

```
add_mult_rec(5) does 1+2*3+4*5 and should return 27
```

But by writing:

```
def add_mult_rec(num):
        if num == 1:
            return num
        elif num % 2 == 1:
            return num * add_mult_rec(num - 1)
        elif num % 2 == 0:
            return num + add_mult_rec(num - 1)
```

my output for add_mult_rec(5) is: `65`

Comment: You're doing `5 * (4 + (3 * (2 + 1)))`. You need to rethink your recursive call. Unless this is to practice recursion, you're much better off using a loop.

Comment: Yes, this is to practice recursion.

Answer (score 3):

The order of operation should be respected, what you wants is actually: 1 + (2 x 3) + (4 x 5) +...

```
def add_mult_rec(num):
        if num <= 1:
            return num
        
        if num % 2 == 1:
            return num * (num - 1) + add_mult_rec(num - 2)
        else:
            return num + add_mult_rec(num - 1)
```